# Is this an accurate windows equivalent to chmod 750?

Tags: windows, permissions, chmod

I need to interpret Linux permissions as windows permissions for work. How I see it (considering only these identity references exist for the file):

- admin group(also owner) with Full control or modify, or write and ReadandExecute each equate to 7.

-User group(group) with ReadandExecute equate to 5

-No guest or everyone group equates to 0

conclusion 750

Any windows system permission experts backed up with credible sources disagree with this logic?

thanks